# dropna results in ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Tags: pandas

I have a large df and when I do the following:

```
df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

However, the following works:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].dropna()
```

The following dtypes are in the df:

```
dtype('float64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int32'), dtype('uint8')]
```

Comment: You wrote ```df.dropna(inplace=True)``` twice- once saying it's working, then that it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference. I had dummies in the df that had dtype uint8. I converted them to int32 and now it is working